# What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?

Tags: javascript

Example from Googles +1 button:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
      {"parsetags": "explicit"}
</script>
```

The script Tag has a src-Attribute **and** content. What does this mean and how does it work?

Comment: Firebug Lite uses this method:  https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Different browsers treat this differently. Some run the content only if the `src` is included without error. Some run it after attempting to include the `src` script, regardless of success. Since this behaviour is unreliable (and [prohibited in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-script-element)), it should be avoided.

Google isn't relying an any specific behaviour. Since the content is just an object literal (a value), executing it would not actually do anything except cause a silent error. Google's code looks at the contents of the `script` tag itself, and adjust its behaviour based on that.

Comment: Is there a cleverer way for the script to look at the contents of its own script tag (specifically), than going through the DOM?

Comment: On all browsers I've worked with, the script content will never be executed if the `src` attribute is present, and actually is not really an object literal, that code would produce a `SyntaxError` if executed, it's simply "JSON text" that the script will use by itself later.

Comment: @Karl used within an external .js file, this will give you the contents of the currently executing <script> node: 

`s=document.getElementsByTagName('script'); text = s[s.length-1].innerHTML;`

I don't think there is any way to fetch the contents of a script node that doesn't involve touching the DOM.

Comment: @CMS works on all browsers except IE. You can see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EjfPM/)

Comment: @jose - your example is not what CMS was refering to. If the code is run as a stand alone statement, it is a syntax error. Your example (and Google's) "works" only because the content of the script element is ingnored due to the *src* attribute.

Comment: @JeremyBanks: "If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough." - Albert Einstein ...I didn't understood a single word and I believe you do not know it yourself well. Sorry, definitely not hurting you.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - try: `document.currentScript` inside your 'src' referenced script to get a reference to the script's own '<script>' tag.

Comment: `{"parsetags": "explicit"}` isn’t an object literal. An object literal is an expression, which must be an expression statement, but expression statements cannot begin with `{`. `{"parsetags": "explicit"}` is invalid syntax if parsed as a script or a module.

Answer (score 29):

If a [script element](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT) has a *src* attribute, the content **must** be ignored, any other behaviour is non-conformant.

It has been suggested in blogs (as a hack) to put content in the element knowing that it won't be evaluated, then use DOM methods to get the content as a string and either *eval* it or insert it in a new script element. Neither of these are a good idea.

Comment: Why is this not a good idea? What if it's used to initialize a third party plugin?

Comment: Old thread but to answer @thekingoftruth's question: html is editable by clients, so run it through eval means giving the user the ability to run arbitrary code, which is a massive security vulnerability.

Comment: @FedericoS—users have the ability to run arbitrary code anyway, I don't see an eval approach as much of a security issue *per se*. It's more just untidy and inefficient given there are much more elegant ways to optionally load code, though it's been popular for some time to just dump everything plus the kitchen sink into the first page and hope caching delivers some efficiencies thereafter. E.g. the home page at Qantas is 24 mB.

Answer (score 15):

After the script has loaded, it looks inside its own script tag to access its content.

It will use some code similar to this:

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var data = eval(scripts[scripts.length - 1].innerHTML);
```

Courtesy of [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/blog/degrading-script-tags/).

Comment: Why not just `document.currentScript`?

Answer (score 13):

According to the [HTML5 draft specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts), `<script>` elements with `src` attributes should only have commented-out code, which is intended to give documentation for the script.  It doesn't appear as though Google is conforming to this specification though.