# Is this a completely anonymous object... if so, how do you access it?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-objects

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean)

I was just viewing [this page](http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/), on how to implements Googles *+1* button. When one implementation (parse explicit) showed, among other things, this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js">
  {parsetags: 'explicit'}
</script>
```

To me this looks like a completely anonymous object, but I could be mistaken.

If it is though, how is it possible to access this seemingly anonymous object? Upon writing this question, I suddenly realized it could probably be done with parsing the DOM, but that seems rather ridiculous.

So, is this an anonymous object? And if so, how *is* this anonymous object utilized? Is this some familiar technique I am unaware of?

Or am I just completely misinterpreting the code altogether, and is this not an anonymous object at all?

Comment: @Felix: Thanks, wasn't aware of the duplicate. Should I vote to close myself too, or just delete the question, in such a case?

Comment: Good question.... :D As no one has answered, I guess deletion is fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hack.

If a script element has a `src` attribute, then the child nodes of the script element should be ignored.

The JS attempts to find its own script element, and then extract the content from it (probably via `innerHTML` but I haven't checked) and parse it.