# Script src inside jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, include

I want to do something like this:

```
            $("#startButton").click(function() {
                <?php if(somecondition){ ?>
                    <script src="some-external-js-srouce"></script>
                    <noscript><img src="irrelevant"></noscript>
<?php } ?>

});
```

Meaning that I want to execute some external javascript inside a jquery function if a button has been clicked. Can you help me?

Comment: `<img src="irrelevant">` is not JavaScript.... you have to bit more clear about what you are trying to do. I understand that you might want to load some external script, but what you want to do with that image tag?

Comment: Your condition is serverside, but your button click is clientside. Basicly how would it ever change on the clients end? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610995/jquery-cant-append-script-element

Comment: The condition is not a problem. It's just a script i got from some tracking i need to insert if the button is being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You're putting HTML inside JavaScript. That's not quite possible.

You probably want [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) to load and execute a script dynamically at runtime. It does not support `<noscript>` but you're using JavaScript for it anyway, so that does not really make sense to me...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to execute a javascript function from an external file then you can try like this -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="myjs.js">
// code that will refer functions of myjs.js

</script>
```

Comment: It's unreliable to combine a `<script>`'s `src` attribute and the tag's contents. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Answer (score 0):

use jQuery.getScript( url, function(){});

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/