# JavaScript <script>...</script> content used as an argument in Google Docs publish scripts

Tags: xhtml, google-apps-script

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean)

If I publish a chart in Google Docs Spreadsheet, I get the following code to access the image:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js">
{"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?
key=...&transpose=0&headers=1&range=A1%3AC72&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"vAxes":...}}
</script>
```

Obviously the javascript program gets the text in ... as an argument.

However, in HTML definition (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html): "If the src has a URI value, user agents **must ignore** the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI."

(Edited: as mentioned in the comment below, this was already discussed and agreed that Google uses DOM to access the content - which is not recommendable.)

But question: how to escape the argument as valid XHTML? It seems that Google has not taken into account that someone would like to add CTYPE definition between  tags. This code does not work:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/static/modules/gviz/1.0/chart.js">
<![CDATA[
{"dataSourceUrl":"//docs.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?
key=...&transpose=0&headers=1&range=A1%3AC72&gid=0&pub=1","options":{"vAxes":...}}
]]>
</script>
```

Comment: RE edit: Use string manipulation to remove the `<![CDATA[` and `]]>` sections.

Answer (score 0):

At the point in time when the script is run, that script element will be the last one on the page. So the external file can easily call something like this:

```
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); s = s[s.length-1];
var input = JSON.parse(s.textContent);
```