# jQuery Email Validator - Implementation Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script to validate the "email" field in a form when the "submit" button is clicked, and everything is working just dandy on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Log8f6dp/)**, but when I implement the script in the head like so...

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#validate').click(function() {
        var sEmail = $('#mail').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
        }
        else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

well, nothing happens. :(

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I didn't understand your question properly. Is it not working on you computer / localserver?

Comment: There is no end `</script>` tag for `jquery.min.js` reference. Tags for Script references should not enclose javascript code

Comment: I think you have to script at the end of the body, Its working fine , coded looking good, no problem. Also you did t close the script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why jquery/javascript code doesn't work when I use it in same script tag with src attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13016496/why-jquery-javascript-code-doesnt-work-when-i-use-it-in-same-script-tag-with-sr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a separate  tag for the embedded code.  Try this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript>
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#validate').click(function() {
            var sEmail = $('#mail').val();
            if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
                alert('Please enter valid email address');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
            if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            }
            else {
                alert('Invalid Email Address');
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });

    function validateEmail(sEmail) {
        var filter = /^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/;
        if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: I probably should have tried this before panicking. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try by return false statement in validate click event

```
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
         $('#validate').click(function() {
               var sEmail = $('#mail').val();
               if ($.trim(sEmail).length == 0) {
                   alert('Please enter valid email address');
                   e.preventDefault();
               }
               if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
                   return true;
               }
               else {
                   alert('Invalid Email Address');
                   //e.preventDefault();
                   return false;
               }
         });
    });
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

There are few thing you need to do.

1. First close the jquery URL script tag
2. Put the script at the end before the closing body tag .

Answer (score 1):

***YOU HAVE PASSED EVENT OBJECT AT THE WRONG FUNCTION.***
**JS CODE**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#validate').click(function(e) {
        var sEmail = $('#email').val();
        if ($.trim(sEmail) === '') {
            alert('Please enter valid email address');
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if (validateEmail(sEmail)) {
            alert("email is fine");
        } else {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
function validateEmail(sEmail) {
    var filter = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    if (filter.test(sEmail)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<input type='email' id='email'>
<button id='validate'>Validate</button>
```