# Why won't this JQuery inner html set work?

Tags: jquery, innerhtml

I've been trying to get this taken care of, and it doesn't seem to want to work. I've scoured the internet and stackoverflow for an answer, but I can't seem to find anything that actually works for this. If anyone can help me out here, that would be awesome!

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box").html("sing!!!!");
        });
        </script>

        <style>
            .box{
            border:2px solid black;
            padding:12px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="box">
            This will be replaced with a JQuery statement.
        </div>
        <p>
            This is text to be left UNALTERED.
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's probably because you are loading the jquery library and declaring script statements in a single tag. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Comment: Side note: `script` tags have no `rel` attribute, and the `type` attribute defaults to `text/javascript` universally, so you should leave `rel` off entirely, and you *can* leave `type` off if you like (if you're using JavaScript).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The script tag for jquery is not closed.

```
 <script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box").html("sing!!!!");
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: Okay, so that's a separate script tag set within the head? Okay, I guess that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

A [`script` tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#the-script-element) can **either** have a `src` attribute to load an external file, **or** inline content, but never both. If you give it both, the inline content is ignored (on most browsers).

So your `script` tag:

```
<script rel="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").html("sing!!!!");
});
</script>
```

...is invalid. You need to end the one loading jQuery, and then open a *new* one for your code:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".box").html("sing!!!!");
});
</script>
```

*(See my comment on the question for why I've removed `rel` and `type` from that.)*