# What happens with a script block with internal and external scripting?

Tags: javascript

Might already be answered but I couldn't find it easily.

Case 1:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='external'>
    'Some script here'
</script>
```

Case 2:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='external'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    'Some script here'
</script>
```

So in case 1, does the src lib get loaded first so you can use it in the internal script block? I tried and apparently, it doesn't work. (What I did was store a variable and it didn't work)

If it is supposed to work, is it any different from case 2?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In-page script content is ignored when there's a "src" attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Case 1 is incorrect. Case 2 is dependent on if you have synchronous or asynchronous code in your external script.

Comment: wait really?  I thought that the content was just dropped on the floor.  Are you talking about the "async" attribute?

Comment: What? No I'm talking about setTimeouts and order of operations.

Comment: oh durr ... I see :-)

Answer (score 2):

src
This attribute specifies the URI of an external script; this can be used as an alternative to embedding a script directly within a document. script elements with an src attribute specified should not have a script embedded within its tags.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/script