# jquery animate image doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html, css

i'm trying to make a image to fade from left on load to some point on the screen. My code seems right,but is not work,nothing happens,please help:
This is my function for the animatetion of the image :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
   $(document).ready(function(2000,slow){
    $(".img-fade").animate({left:200, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
});
    </script>
```

and here is where i implement it in html:

```
<div class="latest-updates-portofolio " >
<div class=".img-fade">
<img src="img/logo.png"  width="180px" height="180px">text
</div>
</div>
```

and the `.img-fade` class is a blank class just to do the function.
And one more quesetion,how do i make it animate to left after 2 seconds after the page has finish loaded?
Thanks.

Comment: Check the console : `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number ` -> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8mRyb/)

Comment: `<div class=".img-fade">` remove `.` not needed

Comment: Added to all of the many other issues in your code.  You have `src` attribute on your script as well as content.  The content of the script is likely ignored.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first issue which is masking the many other issues pointed out by other answers is this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js">
   // YOU HAVE CODE HERE
</script>
```

If your script tag has a `src` attribute, then the contents of the tag (your code) will be ignored.  Because of this, your actual code never executes.

http://jsfiddle.net/t9Z8F

It should be like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
   // YOUR CODE GOES HERE
</script>
```

One script tag to include jquery and another for your code.  Once you fix this, you will see your syntax errors on the console and can begin to debug all of your issues.

Comment: +1 Nice, Sharp eyes :) I missed it seeing the jsfiddle in comments.

Comment: Got a question i want it to apply it two several divs,and they overlap,how can i make that not happen ? thnx.

Comment: @ЗапорожанВиктор That sounds like a separate question which you should post separately complete with full details and a working example so it's easier to answer.

Comment: @JamesMontagne ok thnx i will post new one.tought not to spam the threads.thnx.

Answer (score 0):

by using a `setTimeout` function.
this will delay your animations

```
$(function(){  // DOM ready shorthand

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".img-fade").animate({left:200, opacity:1}, 1500);
    }, 2000 ); // wait 2s before animating

});
```

Theremore you cannot have a **dot** in your `class` : `<div class=".img-fade">` use instead:

```
<div class="img-fade">
```

Additionally if you plan to animate an element using it's `left` property (instead of `margin-left`) make sure to set a CSS `position:` (relative or absolute) for your element!

Comment: @ЗапорожанВиктор I was writing the full answer. Take a look now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `<div class=".img-fade">` div shouldn't have a "." at the beginning of the name. It should look like this: `<div class="img-fade">` - Everything else looks good. Your jQuery wasn't finding any elements matching "img-fade," because the actual name was ".img-fade".

Comment: Everything else does not look good.  The javascript/jquery code has syntax errors.

Comment: True. Changing his code to this should work:
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".img-fade").animate({left:200, opacity:"show"}, 1500);
    });

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(2000,slow){  //syntax error
```

you can't pass parameter within function() it is a syntax error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number .

Try this

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".img-fade").animate({
            left: 200,
            opacity: "show" // wrong instead use 0
        }, 1500);
    });
```

`opacity: "show"` is wrong, instead use `opacity: 0`

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8mRyb/1/)

Comment: Not only no need, it's a syntax error.  You can't name a parameter in a function as a number.