# Call a function from another file

Tags: javascript, html, function, document.write

I want to call the function like I did in the following HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var reg1 = new Image
var red1 = new Image
reg1.src="1.gif"
red1.src="1R.gif"
var reg1s = new Image
var red1s = new Image
reg1s.src="1s.gif"
red1s.src="1sR.gif"
var reg3s = new Image
var red3s = new Image
reg3s.src="3s.gif"
red3s.src="3sR.gif"
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="script.js">
NavigationBar();
</script>
<h1 align="center">Welcome to Drexel!</h1>
<center> <img src="DrexelDragons.png"> </center>
These images are public domain clip art obtained from 
<a href="http://www.clipart.co.uk/"><img src="cwbutton.gif"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

I am calling it from a separate .js file. Here is the code.

```
function NavigationBar()
{
document.write("<a href=\"Home page2.html\" onMouseOver=\"document.thereg1.src=red1.src\" onMouseOut=\"document.thereg1.src=reg1.src\"><img src=\"1.gif\" Name=\"thereg1\"></a>")
return ""
}
```

My problem is that this will run but it wont display the image or do what I want it to do while it is declared as a Function.  If I just put it as a document.write statement it works just fine but I need it as a function.

Comment: I don't think you can mix a script tag that has a src attribute with a script tag that has JavaScript inside it.

Comment: @JasonSperske is correct, that is actually prohibited in HTML5 and will generally have weird inconstancies across browsers.

Comment: So how would you recommend I do this?

Comment: @WillisZawisa see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Don't mix script tags that load an external resource and script tags that should execute their content.  Browsers are required to ignore the content in the tag if the tag has a src attribute:

> If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI

Change it to this and it should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  NavigationBar();
</script>
```

Sources:

[What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean)

http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT