# Javascript String Comparison returning 'undefined' in my div container

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following Javascript code where I am simply comparing two string values and am attempting to return the result in my div container via an innerHTML command.  However, my output is always being displayed as "undefined".

Javascript code:

```
function speak () {

var lang = "fr";
var enlang = "en";  
var n = lang.localeCompare(enlang);

if (n == 0)
    {
        var message1 = "blah";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML= message1;
    }
    else
    {
        var message2 = "blah2";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML = message2;
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="speak.js">speak();</script>
<div id="percentage1"><p></p></div>
```

Comment: code is all okay, check your HTML if it contains element with ID 'percentage1'!

Comment: Is this code running before the element exists in the DOM?

Comment: You cannot include both a `src` attribute on a `<script>` element *and* content inside the `<script>` element. You must separate them into two `<script>` elements, so that one has the `src` and the other contains the code content. This is the likely cause behind your `speak` function not being called, since the content is not necessarily executed depending on the browser (and shouldn't be executed according to the spec). See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6528343/1883647) for further details and links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no call being made to your function.

You could try using `<body onload="speak()">` or something to call it up.

Also try putting the new innerHTML values in string quotations.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function speak() {

var lang = "fr";
var enlang = "en";  
var n = lang.localeCompare(enlang);

if (n == 0)
    {
        var message1 = "blah";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML = "message1";
    }
    else
    {
        var message2 = "blah2";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML = "message2";
    }
}
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="speak()">
    <div id="percentage1">blah blah blah</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: apart from that and there being a space in between speak and the parentheses "()" I don't see any issues, works fine for me

Answer (score 1):

**IF YOU WANT TO LOAD IT IN WINDOW LOAD, YOU CAN WRITE THAT LOGIC IN YOUR JAVASCRIPT ITSELF.**

**HTML**

```
<div id="percentage1"><p></p></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
 window.onload = function speak() {

var lang = "fr";
var enlang = "en";  
var n = lang.localeCompare(enlang);

if (n === 0)
    {
        var message1 = "blah";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML = message1;
    }
    else
    {
        var message2 = "blah2";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML = message2;
    }
};
```

if you want to print within`<p>`tag, use this

```
  window.onload = function speak() {

var lang = "fr";
var enlang = "en";  
var n = lang.localeCompare(enlang);

if (n === 0)
    {
        var message1 = "blah";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').firstChild.innerHTML = message1;
    }
    else
    {
        var message2 = "blah2";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').firstChild.innerHTML = message2;
    }
};
```

**SEE THIS [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dukuqoxi/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the minimalist sample to reproduce your problem?  I took your javascript and made this, which wrote 'blah2' into the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JS Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function speak () {

    var lang = "fr";
    var enlang = "en";  
    var n = lang.localeCompare(enlang);

    if (n == 0)
    {
        var message1 = "blah";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML= message1;
    }
    else
    {
        var message2 = "blah2";
        document.getElementById('percentage1').innerHTML = message2;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="speak()">

Percentage1: <span id="percentage1"></span>

</body>
</html>
```

I think your problem is elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what was happening.  My code was actually correct but when I kept making updates to my server via Filezilla, it was pulling the original code and not properly updating itself.

I fixed this problem by saving my updated .js file to another name and it worked fine.

Thank you all for your support, it is much appreciated!