# Why does this Javascript document.write not execute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I launch this in chrome, nothing appears on the page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>test 4000</title><head>
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
document.writeln("test")
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you shouldn't put inline scripts in a script tag that references an external script

Comment: Maybe you try to open this file right from you disk (I mean not from server). In this case Chrome trying to find including script as file://ajax.googleapis.com...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Comment: Change `<script src="//ajax` to `<script src="http://ajax` if you're running the page locally.

Comment: @Blazemonger there is nothing wrong with the `src="//ajax` it will default to use the same protocol as the page.

Comment: @JezD ...which doesn't work if you're running it as a local file. `src="//` only works when running from a webserver.

Comment: @Guam you've not closed your `<head>` tag, you seem to be opening one inside another and closing neither

Answer (score 6):

you are inserting code in a script tag that you are also using to load an external script (jQuery). you should either do the one or the other.

```
<script>
    document.writeln("test");
</script>
```

if you want both do:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    document.writeln("test");
</script>
```

the [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html) states:

> If the src has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI.

*you do not need to include jQuery to use `document.writeln()`*

Comment: The "type=text/javascript" attribute is redundant, btw. You can safely take it away.

Comment: The relevant reference is http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/scripts.html#edef-SCRIPT which says: “If the `src` has a URI value, user agents must ignore the element's contents and retrieve the script via the URI.”

Comment: @hugomg right. this is html5 only. thanks.

Comment: The reason that this behaviour is in the html5 standard is because it was already implemented by every browser out there. So in practice, ommiting the script type is also an "html4" feature. (This is also why the html5 doctype declaration is the way it is)

Comment: html 4.01 [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/scripts.html#adef-type-SCRIPT) says `The scripting language is specified as a content type (e.g., "text/javascript"). Authors must supply a value for this attribute. There is no default value for this attribute.` although browsers assumed it anyway.