# What does this script tag syntax mean?

Tags: javascript, syntax, standards

I'm sorry for question, because I can't google it (I don't know name of this feature) and can't find it in documentation for script tag. I found it in linkedin API:

```
<script src="https://someurl.com">
    a : 10
    b : 20
    c : 30
</script>
```

What is this? It looks like passing parameters to script, but it was not mentioned in any question like "passing parameters to script"

Comment: You can see a response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Comment: Looks like the [Netflix API](http://developer.netflix.com/docs/JavaScript_APIs) does something similar with JSON.

Comment: Why not just use object with fields instead?

Answer (score 0):

It is a clever way to indeed "pass parameters to a script".

This does not do anything by itself, but some Javascript on your page (such as the one that is being loaded here) could look at the DOM to get to the text content of the script tag, and treat this as input.

Comment: So, this arguments not passed to script and they should be parsed as text. Then what is the benefit? To keep namespace clean?