# Using JQuery to run php whit out refreshing page is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hello as state I am trying to use jquery to run some php without refreshing the page, however I am new to jquery and am having trouble getting it to work, can some one please take a look.

```
<div id="GameBox">
    <a onclick="setscore(1);">Start</a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> 
    function setscore(id) {   
        $('#GameBox').load('PHPsavemove.php?questionsCor=' + id);
    } 
</script>
```

Right now I am getting the error that it does not see my function set score. 
I quote "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setscore"

Please help

Comment: What is the error you get? Also, you should put your code in a separate `script` block to the one which references `jquery.js`

Comment: see edit for exact error

Comment: As @Rory mentioned, a script block should either have content OR an `src`, not both. Because you've set `src`, the content is being ignored. Note that this is [browser-specific](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6528343/622391), and definitely not reliable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should fix it
(Place the code into a separate script tag)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function setscore(id) {   
        $('#GameBox').load('PHPsavemove.php?questionsCor=' + id);
    } 
</script> 
<div id="GameBox">
    <a onclick="setscore(1);">Start</a>
</div>
```