# Snap.load() callback function triggered too late in Safari

Tags: javascript, svg, safari, snap.svg

**PROBLEM**

In my code *MySymbolsObject.js* - code reported inline just for example purposes - set a `window.onload` event in order to `Snap.load()` a svg file and save the svg fragment node in `Symbols.resources`

The last inline `<script>` set a second `window.onload` event containing code that uses the svg node saved in `Symbols.resources`

In Firefox it works flawless printing the node in the console, in Safari `Symbols.resources` is printed as its original 0 value in the console.

I CHECKED

- in the Safari console, after the page fully loads `Symbols.resources` contains the node.
- the expected execution order of the two `onload events` is respected in both the browsers.

My guess is that `Snap.load()` runs asynchronously so It has unpredictable behavior in different browsers.

How can resolve in Safari?

```
<html>
<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="MySymbolsObject.js">

      setEvent( window, 'load', function(){ 
          Snap.load( 'pathToFile.svg', function( svgFrag ){ 
               Symbols.resources = svgFrag;
          });
      });

      Symbols = { 
          resources : 0,
          ...
      }

  </script>


  <script type="text/javascript">

      onload = function (){
          console.log( Symbols.resources )
      }

  </script>

</head>

<body> ... </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This related question might help: [What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean)

Comment: Thanks @Roberto, actually the second script-Tag has not content, I put here just to show the code of _MySymbolsObject.js_ for example purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to postpone the execution of the `window.onload` code until `Symbols.resources` is ready.

The actual code is moved in the `function main()`, `window.onload` just checks repeatedly for `Symbols.resources` to be ready and finally call `main()`.

```
onload = function (){
    if( Symbols.resources ) main();
    else setTimeout( window.onload, 10000 );
}

function main(){
    console.log( Symbols.resources );
}
```