# JavaScript function is not defined in head using onchange event

Tags: php, jquery

I want to select a user name and print something once the name is selected. However, why is "load_new_content()" not defined?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Profile Editor</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#selectedUserId").change(load_new_content());
 });

function load_new_content() {
    alert("hello");
 }

 </script>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php
 error_reporting(-1);
 require('Db.php');

 $db = new Db();
 // var_dump($db);
 $userIds = $db -> getUserIds();
 echo '<select name="selectedUserId" id="selectedUserId" onchange="load_new_content()">';
 echo '<option value="">Choose your CEC User Id</option>';
 foreach($userIds as $ID) {
    echo "<option>".$ID["user_id"]."</option>";
    // echo $userId["user_id"];
    // echo $ID['user_id'];
 }
 echo '</select>';

 ?>
```

Comment: a side note. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrong `<script>` tag declaration.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Need this close tag -->

<script> <!-- Need a Open tag -->

$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#selectedUserId").change(load_new_content());
 });

function load_new_content() {
    alert("hello");
 }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be solved by wrapping the call to `load_new_content` in a function:

```
$("#selectedUserId").change(function(){ load_new_content(); });
```

Also, you are not closing the `<script>` tag that calls jQuery, or opening a new `<script>` tag for the subsequent code. Try:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#selectedUserId").change(load_new_content());
});
function load_new_content() {
   alert("hello");
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Two problems. First one noted by others, you need a separate script tag for your inline JavaScript.

Second, you can't just do

`$("#selectedUserId").change(load_new_content());`

This will just execute the function once when the page loads.

You need to do it like this:

`$("#selectedUserId").change(function() { load_new_content() });`

(note the function call within another function)

or this:

`$("#selectedUserId").change(load_new_content);`

(note the lack of parenthesis)