# Pass variable from php to javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, php

I want a variable that is in php to javascript function argument, but I do not get :( anyone can help me ..

```js
//file js.js
function ComputeTotalPrice(first_meters_price){
  alert(first_meters_price);//result undefined
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    ...
 $first_meters_price = price_type(get_geo_id("Rural"), //returns 4
 
?>
<script src="js.js" >
  ComputeTotalPrice(<? echo $first_meters_price; ?>);
</script>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
 <div id='reserva'>
      ...
 </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean second answer

Comment: Also might need `<?php`

Comment: `<script src="js.js" >` needs to be `<script type="text/javascript">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php $myVar = 5; ?>
<head>...</head>
<body>
    <script>
         var myVarFromPHP = <?php echo $myVar; ?>;
    </script>
    ...
</body>
```

Try seeing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168214/pass-a-php-string-to-a-javascript-variable-and-escape-newlines) stackoverflow answer as well

Comment: @AlbertoSetim Hmmm... When you say it didn't work did it throw an error?

Comment: @AlbertoSetim Also, try not using `<script src="..."> var myVar = <?php ... ?>; </script>` and instead use two separate `script` tags.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned and linked to external answers, content inside a `script` tag is unreliable and even prohibited in some browsers when a `src` attribute is included; as such, it should be avoided.

For this to operate properly, one approach would be to pull the function from `js.js` into the `script` tag like below. It's undesirable but it does function as needed.

```
<?php $first_meters_price = 4; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ComputeTotalPrice(first_meters_price) {
        alert(first_meters_price);
    }
    ComputeTotalPrice(<?php echo json_encode($first_meters_price); ?>);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this works.. but is ot the best way to do this..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php $var_to_js = function_php();?>
<input type='text' class='hide' id='var_to_js' value='<?php echo $var_to_js; ?>'/>
<script>
  var var_from_php = document.getElementById('var_to_js').value;
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```