# Object rotate click JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transform

I have a problem, I don't know why but the script doesn't work. When I `click` in object he must only turn right. `Turn right 90 degress.`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Awesome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
        $('.crossRotate').on('click', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    </script>

    <style>
        object {
            width: 10%;
            height: 10%;
        }

        .crossRotate {
            -webkit-transition-duration: 3s;
            -moz-transition-duration: 3s;
            -o-transition-duration: 3s;
            transition-duration: 3s;
        }

        .crossRotate.active {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
            transform: rotate(360deg);
        }

        body {
            background-color: black;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<object data="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/81/6d/a5/816da533638aee63cfbd315ea24cccbd.jpg"></object>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should use two script tags and not src and content on one tag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Answer (score 0):

You are loading `$('.crossRotate').on('` before the page has loaded, so it will never hit and you don't wrap it in a `<script>` block. Either load the JS at the bottom of the page, or wrap it in `onload`. Try:

```
<script>
    $(function(
        $('.crossRotate').on('click', function(){
          $(this).toggleClass('active');
        });
    ));
</script>
```