# Calling javascript file from html file is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the HTML file to print the output of a javascript file but it doesn't seem to be working - I just end up with a blank page.

**My HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="sketch.js"> setup()</script>       
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fog"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My javascript file** (sketch.js)

```
function setup() {
    s = "hello";
    document.getElementById('fog').innerText = s;        
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does a script-Tag with src AND content mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean)

Comment: Use one `<script>` tag for the external file and another one for the `setup()` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the script calling `setup` near the closing body tag,the dom with `id` `fog` is not present when `setup` is called

```
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <script src="sketch.js"></script>       
    </head>
    <body>
     <div id="fog"></div>
    <script>setup()</script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script tag is synchronous, means that the parser waits and executes the contents of the script BEFORE the html is fully parsed. By the time your script is executed the div is not even there. If you do not want to defer the script or change its location, you can at least use [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```
window.addEventListener(
    "DOMContentLoaded",
     function setup() {
          var s = "hello";
          document.getElementById('fog').innerText = s;        
     },
     false
);
```

in your script.