# How do I make this Javascript function run?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to make an image captcha from scratch for a small project, but in the code below, I can't seem to manage to run the upRAns() function, I can't find the proper syntax anywhere. Any help?

```
for($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++){
  $j = rand(1, 4);
  echo '<img src="images/' . $j . '.png" height = 150 width = 150 class = captcha onclick = "captchaClick(this)" data-target=' . $i . '/>';
  echo '<input type=checkbox class=hidden name=' . $i . '/>';
  if(($i+1)%3 == 0){
    echo '<br>';
  }
  if($j == $ans){
    echo '<script src = "Captcha.js">upRAns(' . $i . ')</script>'; //this line right here
  }
}
```

Comment: A `<script>` tag cannot have both an `src` *and* content. [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean)

Comment: It's php, not javascript

Comment: @DougCoburn it outputs JavaScript

Comment: @DougCoburn the last `echo` injects a `<script` tag which contains a call to a JS function. That's what's being referred to. OP even put a comment next to it in their code. And the first comment by Tyler Roper has already explained why it isn't working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `<script` tag cannot have both a `src` attribute (telling it to load the script content from a separate file) **and** some inline content within the block itself.

You can simply define two separate `<script` tags instead:

```
if($j == $ans)
{
  echo '<script src="Captcha.js"></script>';
  echo '<script>upRAns(' . $i . ')</script>';
}
```