# Some trouble running a javascript function in an external file from php

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file containing the following line;

```
$num= "<script type='text/javascript' src='hn_includes/common.js'>boo();</script>";
```

and of course have a javascript file **common.js** which contains a function **boo()**

This is never called...

In an attempt to debug, I've placed a **console.log("common.js loaded");** at the top of the **common.js** file and this tells me that it is indeed being loaded but the call to function **boo()** never seems to happen.

Additionally, if I simply change my line of code above to;

```
$num= "<script>boo();</script>";
```

and add **boo()** to top of the php file as below;

```
<script>
    console.log ("I'm here");
    function boo()
    {
        console.log("boo");
    }
</script>
```

I get both the "**I'm here**" and also the "**boo**".

Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Load your script with `<script src="...` first, then add another `<script>boo();</script>` to run the function

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean

Comment: so you are getting both "I'm here" and "boo" because "I'm here is a console log which will happen every time you run the page" if you want yo figure out that you can call a specific method create another method `boo()` in the same class and try call it you will find that you can call `boo` or `foo` as you want. Please share some more details if that is not what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

You are only declaring variable in the PHP file. To make it valid accessible in page you need to echo it. like

```
$num= "<script type='text/javascript' src='hn_includes/common.js'>boo();</script>";
echo html_entity_decode($num);
```