# java servlet doesn't work with JavaScript properly

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

```
    out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'>");
    out.println("Calendar.$calendar = document.querySelector('.calendar')");
    out.println("Calendar.$date = document.querySelector('.cur-date')");
    out.println("Calendar.init()");
    out.println("</script>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
```

I'm trying to make the code for Full year calendar that can add to-do list on any date you choose. but it seems to doesn't work.

when I run this code. It's showing me this error.
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerHTML')

how do I fix this problem?

Comment: Basically this is not a servlet or Java question.  The problem is purely in the HTML & Javascript documents.  It is not relevant how they are being served to the browser.

Comment: With script tag you can either provide a source file to load the code from or can have the code mentioned within the script tags, cannot mix both.

Answer (score 0):

Your script tag has a src attrib and contents. This will cause undesired behaviour. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6528325/what-does-a-script-tag-with-src-and-content-mean).

The fix is to change this

```
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'>");
```

into this:

```
out.println("<script type='text/javascript' src='app.js'></script>");
out.println("<script type='text/javascript'>");
```